# Why is Perl not printing all regex matches found in single line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex that matches multiple Strings inside a line in a text file. However, when I use it to try to print all the instances of the captured group it is only printing the first instance.

My regex is:

```
/"resolution.(\w+)/g
```

When feeding the following line to the regex:

```
"signalcfg": "{\"signals\":[{\"order\":1,\"id\":\"oryx_C20C0E15-2028-4F4B-A8DD-0DA8D87B4FF9\",\"name\":\"success\",\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS\",\"testModule\":\"MCSChangeComplaintsStatus\",\"default\":false},{\"order\":2,\"id\":\"oryx_C943ADB8-6FA2-4DA1-B4D7-24515D96B9DA\",\"name\":\"TimeOut\",\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_TIMEOUT\",\"testModule\":\"MCSChangeComplaintsStatus\",\"default\":false},{\"order\":3,\"id\":\"oryx_0CAC0F97-AD57-4C49-807A-B41839191F74\",\"name\":\"Warning\",\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_WARNING\",\"testModule\":\"MCSChangeComplaintsStatus\",\"default\":false},{\"order\":4,\"id\":\"oryx_4583A3EC-DFC8-47B9-9B04-DEE71DC3F17A\",\"name\":\"APIError\",\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_FAIL,resolution.MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_FAIL\",\"testModule\":\"MCSChangeComplaintsStatus\",\"default\":true}]}",
```

It matches all expressions like this:

```
"resolution.COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS
```

I've tried this to print the instances capturing group:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /"resolution.(\w+)/g' FILE_NAME
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m/"resolution.(\w+)/sig' FILE_NAME
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_FOUND
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND
MCS_GET_COMPLAINTS_WARNING
MCS_GET_COMPLAINTS_TIMEOUT
MCS_GET_COMPLAINTS_FAIL
```

But I'm only getting:

```
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_FOUND
```

If I put the above mentioned kind of expressions each in a single line inside the file as this:

```
\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND1\"
\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND2\"
\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND2\"
\"rrcodes\":\"resolution.OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND4\"
```

I do get the expected output:

```
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND1
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND2
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND2
OPEN_IT_COMPLAINTS_NOT_FOUND4
```

Comment: The `-n` option performs one iteration per input line. You have nothing that loops over all the matches in the line.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print "$1\n" for (/"resolution.(\w+)/g)' FILE_NAME`

Comment: That is JSON. Use a proper, existing JSON parser, even in a one-liner. It will be simpler, cleaner and more reliable, and hardly any longer. I downvoted the answers that did not even mention this.

Answer (score 2):

`if /.../g` is using the regex in a scalar context. In this context `/.../g` is returning only a single match. The next `/.../g` will return the next single match etc:

```
$ perl -ne '
   print "$1\n" if /"resolution.(\w+)/g; 
   print "$1\n" if /"resolution.(\w+)/g;' file
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_TIMEOUT
```

If you want all matches you have to either call `/.../g` repeatedly in scalar context or use it in array context. The first option would look like this:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while /"resolution.(\w+)/g' file
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_TIMEOUT
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_WARNING
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_FAIL
```

In array context `/.../g` returns all matches at once as an array, i.e.

```
@matches = /"resolution.(\w+)/
```

Within some command line statement this could  look like this:

```
$ perl -ne 'print map { "$_\n" } /"resolution.(\w+)/g' 
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_TIMEOUT
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_WARNING
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_FAIL
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steffen. This: perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while /"resolution.(\w+)/g' file worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar vs. list context:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$_\n" foreach (/"resolution\.(\w+)/g)' dummy.txt
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_SUCCESS
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_TIMEOUT
MCS_CHANGE_COMPLAINTS_STATUS_WARNING
COMPLAINTS_CHANGE_STATUS_FAIL
```

i.e. `/g` only returns multiple results if the regex gets repeatedly executed. Your command line only executed the match once.

Maybe the following code example makes it more clear;

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $re    = qr/string\.(\w+)/;
my $input = "asdlkj string.TEST1 daklkl string.TEST2 kasöldk";

my($scalar) = ($input =~ /$re/g);
print "SCALAR: $scalar\n";

my @array   = ($input =~ /$re/g);
print "ARRAY:  @array\n";

exit 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This: perl -ne 'print "$_\n" foreach (/"resolution\.(\w+)/g)' dummy.txt did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see OPEN_IT in your input file.

Try looping over the matches instead:

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" for (/"resolution.(\w+)/g)' FILE_NAME
```

The parenthesis give the match a list context, the for will set `$_` to each match one at a time and call `print "$_\n"` on each.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. Just save all the matched in an array @x:

`perl -ne 'say join "\n",@x if @x=/\"resolution.(\w+)/g' FILE_NAME`

@x will be evaluated (by `if`) to be true if it's not empty.

Comment: I prefer such a solution that can save a for-loop (whenever possible).